# Reporting the results of CCA (vegan)

Tags: r, vegan

I've done a CCA analysis with the R package vegan on some macrofaunal data and environmental variables, trying to figure out which variables affect the macrofauna and how much. My CCA output is as follows:

```
Call: cca(formula = abun_df ~ NH4_inv_PW + C_1cm + PLI + season_year, data = env_PLI)

              Inertia Proportion Rank
Total          1.2647     1.0000     
Constrained    0.4077     0.3224    4
Unconstrained  0.8570     0.6776   20
Inertia is scaled Chi-square 

Eigenvalues, and their contribution to the scaled Chi-square 

Importance of components:
                        CCA1   CCA2    CCA3     CCA4    CA1    CA2     CA3     CA4     CA5     CA6     CA7     CA8     CA9    CA10
Eigenvalue            0.2137 0.1369 0.04801 0.009139 0.1727 0.1386 0.07814 0.07174 0.06194 0.05172 0.04864 0.04413 0.03307 0.02865
Proportion Explained  0.1689 0.1082 0.03796 0.007226 0.1366 0.1096 0.06178 0.05672 0.04897 0.04089 0.03846 0.03489 0.02614 0.02265
Cumulative Proportion 0.1689 0.2772 0.31512 0.322350 0.4589 0.5685 0.63029 0.68702 0.73599 0.77688 0.81534 0.85023 0.87638 0.89903
                         CA11    CA12    CA13    CA14    CA15    CA16     CA17     CA18     CA19     CA20
Eigenvalue            0.02083 0.01980 0.01885 0.01825 0.01540 0.01308 0.009518 0.005976 0.003381 0.002617
Proportion Explained  0.01647 0.01566 0.01490 0.01443 0.01218 0.01034 0.007526 0.004725 0.002673 0.002069
Cumulative Proportion 0.91550 0.93116 0.94606 0.96049 0.97266 0.98301 0.990533 0.995258 0.997931 1.000000

Accumulated constrained eigenvalues
Importance of components:
                        CCA1   CCA2    CCA3     CCA4
Eigenvalue            0.2137 0.1369 0.04801 0.009139
Proportion Explained  0.5241 0.3358 0.11776 0.022417
Cumulative Proportion 0.5241 0.8598 0.97758 1.000000

Scaling 2 for species and site scores
* Species are scaled proportional to eigenvalues
* Sites are unscaled: weighted dispersion equal on all dimensions
```

And some significance tests:

```
> #is CCA significant?
> anova(Koverhar_CCA)
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: cca(formula = abun_df ~ NH4_inv_PW + C_1cm + PLI + season_year, data = env_PLI)
         Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)    
Model     4   0.40769 5.3515  0.001 ***
Residual 45   0.85705                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #are axes significant?
> anova(Koverhar_CCA, by = "axis")
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Forward tests for axes
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: cca(formula = abun_df ~ NH4_inv_PW + C_1cm + PLI + season_year, data = env_PLI)
         Df ChiSquare       F Pr(>F)    
CCA1      1   0.21365 11.2181  0.001 ***
CCA2      1   0.13689  7.1873  0.001 ***
CCA3      1   0.04801  2.5207  0.017 *  
CCA4      1   0.00914  0.4799  0.931    
Residual 45   0.85705                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #are vectors significant?
> anova(Koverhar_CCA, by = "term", permutations = 999)
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: cca(formula = abun_df ~ NH4_inv_PW + C_1cm + PLI + season_year, data = env_PLI)
            Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)    
NH4_inv_PW   1   0.10039 5.2713  0.001 ***
C_1cm        1   0.07373 3.8715  0.003 ** 
PLI          1   0.08864 4.6540  0.001 ***
season_year  1   0.14492 7.6092  0.001 ***
Residual    45   0.85705                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Am I correct when I interpret this to mean that:

1) the model explains ~32% of the observed variation

2) the first two axis of CCA are significant, and explain ~52% and ~34% of the variation in the model, respectively

3) all four environmental variables (NH4_inv_PW + C_1cm + PLI + season_year) included in the model are significant

Also, is there any way to find out how much of the variation in the macrofaunal data is explained by each environmental variable? I'm new to statistical analysis, and my supervisors haven't used R (or, apparently, CCA), so I'm slightly lost on how to use it and interpret the results.

Comment: I think, these questions are not so much about programming, but rather about statistics. Maybe more suitable for the Crossvalidated forum https://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Koverhar? In Hangö (Tvärminne)?

Comment: Yes, that's the place. This is Pirita, by the way.